# Create meeting using skype for business online Bad Request Error

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I am trying to create meeting using Skype for business online - SKYPE WEB SDK APIs as bellow.

```
var meeting = skyon.skypeWebApp.conversationsManager.createMeeting();
meeting.subject('Planning meeting');
meeting.accessLevel("Everyone");
meeting.expirationTime(new Date + 24 * 3600 * 5);

meeting.onlineMeetingUri.get().then( function(uri) {
   alert("Meeting successfully Created : "+uri);
   var conversation = app.conversationsManager.getConversationByUri(uri);
},function (error) {
    alert("Meeting.onlineMeetingUri Error: "+error);
});
```

On browser getting bellow error :
[image]
and bellow error getting displayed in alert.

```
 Meeting.onlineMeetingUri Error: Error: 
 POST https://webpoolmaain102.infra.lync.com/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/112122499541/
 onlineMeetings/myOnlineMeetings failed: Bad Request
```

Any help appriciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved with below code, Its something related to syntax.

```
const conversationsManager = skyon.skypeWebApp.conversationsManager;
const subject = "testing";

alert('Scheduling Meeting...');
// @snippet
const meeting = conversationsManager.createMeeting();
meeting.subject(subject);
meeting.accessLevel('Everyone');
meeting.onlineMeetingUri.get().then(uri => {
    alert("uri : "+uri);
    alert("meeting.joinUrl : " + meeting.joinUrl());
}, error => {
    alert(error);
});
```

**Edit** :
   These two lines have caused the issue and I just commented out them.

```
 // meeting.expirationTime(new Date + parseInt(expirationTimeInSec));
 // meeting.leaders(leadersSipUris);
```